# Type casting using string for type

Tags: php, laravel-5, typecast-operator

I have table `settings` with columns: 
`value` - varchar type contains setting value and `type` - enum type contains variable types `"int", "string", "float"`. How can I use string from `type` column to cast value to this type?

I'm trying to do it in my model but it doesn't work:

```
public function getValueAttribute($value){
    return ($this->type)$value;
}
```

Comment: Look into using `settype()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`settype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) function :

```
<?php 

$var = 42;
var_dump($var);  //  int 42
$type = 'string';
settype($var, $type);
var_dump($var);  //  string '42'
```

Adapted to your code snippet :

```
public function getValueAttribute($value){
    settype($value, $this->type);
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a dynamic typecasting like that, instead you'll have to use a function for that. `settype()` takes two arguments, the original value, and the new type you want to typecast it to.

```
public function getValueAttribute($value){
    settype($value, $this->type);
    return $value;
}
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php

Comment: You are returning the result of `settype()`, which will always ba a `bool`. You need to return `$value` instead ;)

Comment: You know, I pressed edit just as you posted your comment ;-) But cheers for pointing it out! ;-)